# How to replicate consul catalog services from data center to another?

Tags: consul

We have two data centers in consul

1. Machine 1 & 2 as primary data center
2. Machine 3 & 4 as secondary data center

Is it possible to replicate catalog services registration from primary to secondary?

Comment: Hi @Sahadevan, Consul already allows for services to be resolved across federated data centers by issuing cross-datacenter RPCs to resolve the service lookups. Could you share a bit more detail as to why you're looking to actually replicate the catalogs? Consul doesn't support catalog replication today, but this feature request has come up a few times, and I would like to better understand how you might use it if we were to build it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @BlakeCovarrubias. Basically we want to make consul setup DR(Disaster Recovery) ready. In our case we have limited servers, so we opted for 2 servers in each data center (primary & secondary). The two data centers are not federated. The end users uses the primary data center to register service for lookups. Only in case of  DR, the end users are switched to secondary data center, so we want the same replica of primary data centers service look ups in secondary as well.